# Definition of slope of parametric tangent

Tags: calculus, derivatives, parametric

Let $x = u(t)$ and $y = v(t)$ be a parametric representation of a curve.

If we assume $u$ is one-one on some open interval in $t$, we can define $f = v \circ u^{-1}$. Then the curve $(u(t), v(t))$ on that interval is the curve $(x, f(x))$ for $x = u(t)$.

Next if we assume $u$ and $v$ are differentiable and $u'(t) \neq 0$, then we have

$$f'(x) = \frac{v'(t)}{u'(t)}. \tag{*}\label{*}$$

Usually I see the slope of the tangent line defined by \eqref{*}. But what happens if u is not one-one on any interval surrounding $t$ and $u'(t) \neq 0$? For example

$$u(t) = \begin{cases} t^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right) + \frac{t}{2} & t \neq 0 \\ 0 & t = 0 \end{cases}$$

at $t = 0$. We can still compute $v'(t)/u'(t)$ and it seems like a reasonable slope for the tangent, but we cannot define an $f$. So it seems more straightforward to define the slope of the tangent line to be $v'(t)/u'(t)$. Then we have a theorem that says that $f'(x) = u'(t)/v'(t)$ when $f(x)$ exists.

Comment: I fear that your $u(t)$ is not defined at $t = 0;$ however, I assume that you are taking its continuous extension by defining $u(0) = 0.$ (By the Squeeze Theorem, we have that $\lim_{t \to 0} u(t) = 0.$)

Comment: Ultimately, I think the point is that if $u(t)$ is one-to-one on some open interval in $\mathbb R,$ then the curve parametrized by $\mathbf r(t) = \langle u(t), v(t) \rangle$ is in fact a function, as you have observed. But even if this is not the case on some open interval containing $t = t_0$ for which $u'(t_0) \neq 0,$ it remains true that the line tangent to the curve parametrized by $\mathbf r(t) = \langle u(t), v(t) \rangle$ at a point $t = t_0$ is $\mathbf L(t) = t \langle u'(t_0), v'(t_0) \rangle + \langle u(t_0), v(t_0) \rangle.$

Comment: Fixed the undefined at $t = 0$ issue, my bad. The point is that it is possible to have a tangent line with a slope $\neq \pm \infty$, but $f$ still does not exist. Is that correct?

Comment: Even if the slope of the tangent line were $\pm \infty,$ you could still parametrize the line. Consider for instance the parametrization of the vertical lines $\mathbf r(t) = \langle 0, t \rangle$ for any real number $t.$ But yes, if $x = u(t)$ is one-to-one, then you can define the function as you have.